# How can I start new line in the email in SMTP

Tags: c, email, smtp

I'm writing program, that can send emails through SMTP, on C/C++ using cURL library.

I have got problem - I can't start new line in email.

I tried using `'\0'` and `'\n'` symbols.

Comment: Slash and backslash doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for '\r' information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `\r\n` not `/n`.

Same goes to `\0`

Comment: In program i use '\n' and \0. I sealed only only in question.